# How to handle UnauthenticatedException with Shiro

Tags: shiro, guice-3

I have a method in my resource with @RequiresGuest annotation. When logged in user hits the link it rightfully throws an `UnauthenticatedException` with this message

> Attempting to perform a guest-only operation.  The current Subject is
>   not a guest (they have been authenticated or remembered from a
>   previous login).  Access denied.

But how do I handle it? How do I, for example, redirect the request to logout page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually dependent upon your chosen MVC framework:

- Some UI mechanisms (e.g. JSP) allow you to have an 'error page' that you can use to process any exception.
- More elegant UI frameworks have 'catch all' exception handlers and/or controllers that allow you to do anything you want (inspect the exception, set an HTTP status code, redirect the end user to an error page specific to that particular problem, etc).

However, if you do not wish to use an MVC mechanism for this, it is possible to create a Servlet Filter that would do this:

The filter would execute the FilterChain in a try/catch block, catching an AuthorizationException.  If it catches one, it issues a 302 redirect to an 'unauthorizedUrl'.

The reason Shiro's existing filters do not do this is because they authorize the Subject before ever invoking the FilterChain: 
if the Subject does not meet authorization criteria, *the filter chain is never even invoked* (and therefore there is no AuthorizationException to catch).

If you would like to see alternative behavior in Shiro, please file an [issue](http://shiro.apache.org/issues.html) and discuss it as a potential new feature.

Comment: In Shiro 1.2.1, any Shiro exception gets wrapped into a generic ServletException. See AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal. So catching a ShiroException in your filter won't work.